# Conditions for Anti-Differentiability

Tags: calculus

Taking the anti-derivative (or integral) of a function can be a difficult problem. What are some conditions that ensure that a function is anti-differentiable, or that show that it is not anti-differentiable?

Comment: Function must be continuous. Or monotone. Do you familiar with Riemann integral?

Comment: There are different notions of antidifferentiability (typically, we call such a property *integrability* instead), and different notions generally enjoy different sufficient conditions, so it would be useful if you specified what type of integrability you were interested in. On the other hand, perhaps you mean (given the comment "taking the antiderivative of a function can be a difficult problem"), conditions that guarantee that a given function has an antiderivative expressible as a composition of elementary functions?

Comment: Are you speaking about a "closed form" of the anti-derivative, or just an "area under the curve"?  Note that Riemann integrability requires continuity at all but a countable number of points in the given interval.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: I think OP wants condition for existence of $F$ with $F'=f$.

Comment: @Gary. yes. It's difference in terminology.

Comment: @Norbert Weiner: Sorry to disappoint you, considering you came back from the grave just to ask this, but I think the closest there is is absolute continuity.

Comment: I think what Norbert Weiner meant were conditions that assured the function is the derivative of some function.

Answer (score 3):

It will take you a few years to get to this. A bounded function is Riemann integrable, on a closed interval, if and only if the set of points at which it is discontinuous has measure zero. This result is probably due to Lebesgue, let me look up some things. In Royden, exercise 2b on page 82. In Berberian, page 268, Theorem 5.13.7.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability

The standard sort of example is this: taking, say, $0 \leq x \leq 1,$ whenever $x$ is irrational define $f(x) = x.$ However, when $x = p/q$ is a fraction in lowest terms, meaning integers $p,q > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1,$ then take
$$ f \left( \frac{p}{q} \right) = p \sin \left( \frac{1}{q} \right).  $$

This function $f$ is discontinuous at every rational number. However, fiddling a bit shows that $f$ is continuous at all irrational numbers. That is, in order for a rational number to get very close to a fixed irrational number $\alpha,$ it is necessary for the denominator $q$ to become very large, which then implies that $f(p/q)$ is quite close to $p/q$ and therefore quite close to $\alpha.$ Modest use of Diophantine approximation. So, the thing is Riemann integrable. So There.

Comment: I think what Norbert Weiner meant was that the function is the derivative of some function. (definite integrable or anti-differentiable as opposed to integrable)

Comment: @JacobWakem, I can take the definite integral from $0$ to some $X$ with the same iff conditions, resulting in an antiderivative. I admit, I am not sure what the original question meant. Sometimes I answer the question that should have been asked...

Comment: @JacobWakem Looking at your version again, I suspect that one would require continuity for your condition. I also suspect that we won't hear from the person asking again.

Answer (score 0):

If f is Riemann integrable, then the anti-derivative is the integral from a to x of f(y) dy  whenever the anti-derivative exists. Thus if you have the definite integral, all you have left is to test to see if it has derivative f. I don't know if there is anything nicer.

Comment: Also I think continuous is necessary/sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning functions of real variables:
Any function which is Riemann integrable is anti differentiable. 
Any continuous function is Riemann integrable.
Any non decreasing function defined on [a,b] is Riemann integrable on [a,b].
Any non increasing function defined on [a,b] is Riemann integrable on [a,b]

These came from an IBL Real Analysis packet by Mahavier.

A function of complex variables is anti-differentiable on a region G if it is continuous on G, and if it integrates to 0 over any simple closed polygonal path in G.

From *A First Course in Complex Analysis*, Matthias Beck